# Spring Jackson custom Deserializer does not called

Tags: spring, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a Spring project, and I try to add a custom deserializer to deserialize Date properties depend on their format.
If I use it as annotation on Date property, it works fine.
But if I add the deserializer to my object mapper, it does not called when Jackson deserialize a date.

I try to apply my custom deserializer like this:

```
    @Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, false);
    return mapper;
}
```

I don't want to apply an annotation on Date properties every time, I want to use this deserializer by default.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks the help for everyone.
Finally I found the answer at [spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.deserializerByType(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
   }
}
```

Comment: Great! You can upvote answers if they helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given that if you use the deserializer in an annotation on Date property then I would say that this ObjectMapper is not being used for deserialization. Try the following:

```java
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
   MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
   jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
   return jsonConverter;
}
```

Comment: You could right, maybe Jackson does not use that ObjectMapper I define in my configuration class. So I added the Bean you advised, but when Jackson deserializing a Date, my deserializer still is not called.

Comment: Well, then the only option is that you are importing a different `Date` in your `ObjectMapper` than the one that you have in your model. It is highly unlikely that this is the case, but can you double-check it? Minor detail that is not related: you have `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, false);` duplicated in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have doubt how you try to use this `ObjectMapper` bean inside your application.

I trust you already know that this bean is need to created inside a `Configuration` class. If not your bean will not register in the context. Like this for example,

```
@Configuration
public class MapperConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, false);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The second problem might be how you try use this `ObjectMapper` bean. If your create new instance of `ObjectMapper` like this *`ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();`*, that instance will not have your custom deserializer and stuff. What you can do is `@Autowire` the `ObjectMapper` instance that you have already created.

Comment: I define ObjectMapper bean in '@Configuration' class. I don't want to use ObjectMapper "manually", I was told Jackson use that ObjectMapper defined at Bean. But it seems to it it does not.

Comment: Can you add code for your `DateDeserializer` and add where you deserialize.

Comment: Also make sure your configuration class in same `base-package`